# How to apply different zones to wired LAN with firewalld without end user intervention?

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, firewalld

Using firewalld and NetworkManager, how do I apply different zones to different wired connections like one could do with private/public profiles on Windows or wireless connection on Ubuntu?
Only one wired NIC is present and all wired connections are shown as "Wired connection 1".
Users may be someone else than me, other user won't switch profile themselves as they do not care about security.

Comment: Create a new wired connection with the same settings as the first one. Call it "Public Wired" or something. Change `firewalld` profile to public in this connection. You will need to manually choose which connection to use when you plug in to different LAN sockets. This is just an idea. I have not tested it. So, I am writing it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Good idea, downside is if someone else than me use the computer, they will just use the trusted profile even while at unknown places and no amount of education will prevent lazyness. Should have be more precise in my question and ask "without user intervention".

Comment: I still don't have a solution for your problem. Wired connections are expected to be "permanent". One idea is to set the default `firewalld` setting for the ethernet connection to public profile. Unless your users run servers or remote protocols like `ssh`, your other users should be able to browse the internet etc.